# Keycloak login page says "Page not found"?

Tags: keycloak

I downloaded the latest Keycloak (17.0.0), start it with `kc.bat start-dev` and when I open `localhost:8080` it redirects to `localhost:8080/auth` and this page is shown:

[image]

I can't make it work and get the page I get when I start the Keycloak standalone version 12...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the admin authentification in keycloak 17 is `localhost:8080`  without /auth
you should run kc.bat start-dev on your cmd after check this url it worked for me.
if it doesn't work try to re-run your cmd
[image: Keycloak admin interface]

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I've tried to use keycloak 16 that has a login page at `http://localhost:8080/auth`. Then I've migrated to keycloak 20 that has a login page at `http://localhost:8080/`.

The browser has cached `http://localhost:8080/auth` and redirected me to this address every time I've tried to open `http://localhost:8080/`, so I've received "Page not found" error. I've tried to open login page in anonymous tab and it worked as expected.

To sum up, make sure to clear browser cache after migrating to keycloak 17+.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your browser's cache and cookies and then try accessing the Keycloak URL again

Answer (score 1):

Although clearing the browser's cache might work, try accessing the Keycloak's administration UI page directly (`http://localhost:8080/admin/master/console/`)

Answer (score 1):

Previously, the default login screen used to appear directly at `localhost:8080/auth/`, but now it's just `localhost:8080`. This change has been introduced in the newer versions of Keycloak.